# Filter "me in CC/BCC" emails, considering email thread history

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, email-filter

So, it is pretty common to filter emails where one is in CC/BCC and not in TO. I know how to create such a filter.

However, the issue is that sometimes I do reply to an email in a thread where I'm only in CC, and from that point on I'd like the subsequent emails in that thread not to be filtered out.

Any ideas how this may be done?

Comment: If you have O365 for Business Plus, this can be accomplished through Microsoft Flow.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, from the perspective of Outlook client, you can create Outlook rules to move all “me in CC” emails to a specified folder you want. However, Outlook rules will be applied to all the emails you received, and I am afraid that we could not make the subsequent emails in that thread not to be filtered out.